# WiFi dropouts with router but not with mobile WiFi hotspot in elementary OS

Tags: dual-boot, wifi, microsoft-windows

Recently I dual booted my laptop HP Pavilion Notebook ab219tx with Windows 10 and elementary OS 0.3.2. At first it connected to my WiFi but poor signal and internet speed is also very slow even through I am near to the router and after some time it just continuously connecting and disconnecting but when I tried with my mobile hotspot it just worked fine.So

Comment: To know your chipset wifi card, try in a terminal: sudo lshw -C network.  Copy & paste the results.

Comment: /0/100/1c.2/0  wlano  network  RTL8723BE  PCIe wireless network adapter @bitseater

Answer (score 1):

HP has recently been using only one antenna on a wireless card with two connectors.  Larry Finger with some help from Realtek came up with the solution

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build essential
git clone git://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
git checkout rock.new_btcoex
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot. Then try

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Check to see if wireless access points are detected

```
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|signal'
```

If nothing is detected or very weak signal, then try

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

Then test to check wifi signal strength

```
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|signal'
```

One or the other `ant_sel` parameter settings should result in better wifi signal strength and you can set it with

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=X" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl-ant-sel.conf
```

Where X is either 1 or 2 based on what gave you better results

Answer (score 0):

This wifi network card has some issues with kernels in Trusty Ubuntu and derivates. You can try from terminal:

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

This trick makes possible a new management of the card and its prevent the card to go to suspend mode.

You must restart your computer after use this command,  or reload the driver with these commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

More info about this known bug for Ubuntu 14.04 and derivates at:

[Ubuntu bugs at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1240940)

If this option doesn't work, you can install a new Realtek driver from the rtwifi_new repo:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

And then reboot or reload the driver how it explain before.